# PostgreSQL unable to divide?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm recently migrating from MySQL to Postgres, as I am now running a OSM tile server that requires Postgres / Postgis in order to function, and I see no reason to waste RAM by having 2 databases running at the same time. I am noticing many nuances in Postgres but one thing that bugs me is division does not seem to be working. I can not divide! Am I doing something wrong here? 197/201 should return 0.980099502

```
   Core=# SELECT SUM(197/201);
    sum 
   -----
      0
   (1 row)


   Core=# SELECT SUM(197+201);
    sum 
   -----
    398
   (1 row)

   Core=# SELECT SUM(197*201);
     sum  
   -------
    39597
   (1 row)

   Core=# SELECT SUM(197-201);
    sum 
   -----
     -4
   (1 row)
```

Comment: you're dividing ints, so you get an integer result.

Comment: Cast to FLOAT or NUMERIC to get precision. Eg. `SELECT SUM(197/201::FLOAT);`

Comment: This is not off topic. Why are there even close votes?

Comment: So in practice doing SUM(197/201::FLOAT); works and I get the proper result, but when I put a query in it does not work.      Core=# SELECT SUM("Viewed") FROM XFilesTV;
 sum 
-----
 197
(1 row)

Core=# SELECT COUNT("Title") FROM XFilesTV;
 count 
-------
   201
(1 row)
Core=# SELECT CAST(((SUM("Viewed")/COUNT("Title"))*100) AS DECIMAL(3,2)) AS "Total" FROM XFilesTV;
 Total 
-------
  0.00
(1 row)

Answer (score 2):

Postgres does integer division, so 1/2 = 0.  You can try to add a decimal point to get another answer, `1.0/2`.

You can read the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-math.html).